# What is the takeoff thrust of a CFM56 engine?

Tags: boeing-737, thrust

So, to be more clear I currently have an assignment about the Boeing 737-800. 
I have to find out the total takeoff distance of the aircraft. I'm using Anderson's book " Aircraft Performance and Design" and I'm quoting that a turbofan engine is affected from the velocity of the aircraft.
Anderson uses this equation: T = k1 - k2*V + k3*(V^2) where k1,2,3 are constants from engine to engine. At his example he uses a Gulfstream IV aircraft and takes the constants as below (chapter 6, example 6.6):  [image]
The constants are selected for the takeoff phase. I guess that these values come from the manufacturer but I cant find this type of info anywhere. Not even a number about the takeoff thrust. The only thing that I can find is the maximum takeoff thrust which is the max thrust available from the engines.

Comment: Please look into Type Certificate DataSheet of variants you interested.

Comment: Given a set of environment conditions: get Vr and Takeoff distance (at TOGA) for three different GW from B737 manuals; then solve a system of linear equations. Those 3 constants are not published and probably Safran's engine model is more complex anyway...

Answer (score 1):

> Developing 21,600 to 33,000 pounds of takeoff thrust, the CFM56-5B is the only engine that can power every model in the Airbus A320ceo family.

[Safran Aircraft Engines](https://www.safran-aircraft-engines.com/commercial-engines/single-aisle-commercial-jets/cfm56/cfm56-5b)